# Imacros Writing Double Quotes to html File, why?

Tags: imacros

I have imacros go on a webpage and download the extraction as an html file. But for some reason it is writing doubles quotes inside the file breaking links. How to fix this?

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript or EVAL

the code is `text=text.replace(/""/g,'"');`

http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

Edit:

Try this out to:

```
text=text.replace(/\"\"/g,'"');
```

Some special characters are written like this \s \n \r  /

Comment: well first of all i am using eval to get the output mentioned above. Secondly, I did try the solution you mentioned, it still did not remove the quotes. I think that when imacros writes to file it is then this occurs not before.

Comment: Then this maybe the issue with your file. Excel sometimes puts "" in the text. Try JavaScript scripting and make a script that removes the " . I will edit for another possible solution.